# How to load the definition of a case type with the CaseType API

Tags: api, civicase

I am trying to use the CaseType API to create a case_type but I can not find any documentation on how to set the **definition** parameter. Any hints or should I just dive into the code?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably actually easiest to look at the code. CRM_Case_BAO_CaseType::convertDefinitionToXML() gives the list of array elements to set, e.g.

```
$definition = array(
  'activityTypes' => array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
  ),

  'statuses' => array(
    'blah1',
    'blah2',
  ),
// etc...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Api Explorer to fetch an existing case type with definition and inspect it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Coleman, pretty ad I did not think of that myself :-(